# OracleDataAdapter can't get the data query by the sql string contaning inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, inner-join

OracleDataAdapter returns no rows, but the query string works in SQLDeveloper .

```
select * 
from MESSAGE_YXX 
inner join EMPLOYEE_YXX SedPerson ON MESSAGE_YXX.SPID=SedPerson.id
```

but it works when I change "inner join " to "left join"

thanks.

Comment: Why dont you add the Oracle tag ?

Comment: Given it works on left join does EMPLOYEE_YXX contain the matching ids . It helps in the query not to use * but explicitly choose the fileds - e.g. MESSAGE_YXX.SPID, SedPerson.id. In this case I suspect SedPerson.id will show as NULL

Comment: +1 I ought learn to read question more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from (
select * 
from MESSAGE_YXX 
join EMPLOYEE_YXX SedPerson ON MESSAGE_YXX.SPID=SedPerson.id
);
```

I remember cases where this helped when the query was not returning all columns.

Besides I never write inner, it is an optinal keyword.